# How to combine gift cards into one based on availability using Google sheet formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

For example, Jenny need to use

"J6H6-8GX3JX-NTA1 $30

J6H6-8GX3JX-NTA8 $15

J6H6-8GX3JX-NTA8 30"

To make a total amount of $75

If the gift card code has been assigned to customers,  mark "Yes" in the cell.

here is the sheet link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nhKAJiDTXczJUwLv4E48QsOqiAkMgCUj1cvESQTda5c/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: How come coupon J6H6-8GX3JX-NTA1 is both 30 and 15 at the same time

Comment: Please check the posted answer and let me know if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(countif(transpose(SPLIT(I2:I,CHAR(10))),A2:A)>0,"YES","NO"))
```

[image: Here's the result after replicating:]

Comment: Should you have further question in respect to the posted answer, feel free to let me know.